# Spring REST - binding GET parameters to list of nested objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My question is almost 1:1 as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36650051/spring-rest-binding-get-parameters-to-nested-objects). The only difference (and struggle) I have is that my "data container" has a collection of objects. It looks like this:

```
public class A {
    int plainFieldA;
    B fieldB;
    List<B> collectionB = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class B {
    int plainFieldB;
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@GetMapping("")
public Entity getAll(A reqParam) {
    return getAll(reqParam);
}
```

Is it possible to define `collectionB` in params of the url `http://localhost/api/test?plainFieldA=1` without creating a converter ? @GameSalutes correctly pointed out that since spring `4` we can do `fieldB.plainFieldB=2` so the url will be: `http://localhost/api/test?plainFieldA=1&fieldB.plainFieldB=2` but the question is can we do soemthing similar with `collectionB` without creating a converter ?

Comment: That's a good question. I would assume it's not possible, as there would be a problem of representation of values in a list. How would you represent them? collectionB[0].plainFieldB? And if you have 100 values? Don't forget that a ``Get`` mapping relies on the http ``GET`` method and there is a limit to the size of a QueryString.

Comment: I would choose to make a `POST` call for such a scenario because of the limit in character size for `GET` method

Comment: Looks like you are trying to implement search to search something based on different parameters. If you want to implement search based on different parameters then I will recommend you to use "Interpreter pattern" without worrying on additional handling. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can make the request like this:

```
http://localhost/api/test?plainFieldA=1&fieldB.plainFieldB=2&collectionB[0].plainFieldB=9
```

Or encoding the request, for postman:

```
http://localhost/api/test?plainFieldA=1&fieldB.plainFieldB=2&collectionB%5B0%5D.plainFieldB=9
```

With two objects in request:

```
http://localhost/api/test?plainFieldA=1&fieldB.plainFieldB=2&collectionB%5B0%5D.plainFieldB=9&collectionB%5B1%5D.plainFieldB=11
```

The result with breakpoint in the IDE:

[image]

Comment: Oh, well.. so long to my "I would assume it's not possible". I even literally wrote the syntax to use. :D Well deserved bounty, if the answer gets accepted!

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you. I clicked bounty button but it says "You may award your bounty in 14 hours" (and can't be transfered). So I will do that in 14 hours. Thank you.

Comment: Do you recomend `POST` over `GET` when it comes to searching by given criteria ?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I recommend in this case POST over GET, in case you send more complex objects than a simple key/value. If one day you have a list with many elements, GET will bring you problems and also at design level you are sending an object.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer works like a charm but I'm adding this answer as an alternative if someone reaches url size limit or some other reason.

Following [this thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/353086/what-is-a-proper-way-to-do-a-complex-restful-search-method/353105#353105?newreg=d5e6360ebf2b434da957a9faa10bffe0) advice, here is how I've done.

- Frontend: stringify your object than encode it in base64 for submission.
- Backend: decode base64 string then convert the string json into desired object.

It isn't the best for debugging your API with postman but it is working as expected for me.

> **Original object:** { page: 1, size: 5, filters: [{ field: "id", value: 1, comparison: "EQ" }
>
> **Encoded object:** eyJwYWdlIjoxLCJzaXplIjo1LCJmaWx0ZXJzIjpbeyJmaWVsZCI6ImlkUGFyZW50IiwiY29tcGFyaXNvbiI6Ik5VTEwifV19

```
@GetMapping
fun list(@RequestParam search: String?): ResponseEntity<ListDTO> {
    val filter: SearchFilterDTO = decodeSearchFieldDTO(search)
    ...
}

private fun decodeSearchFieldDTO(search: String?): SearchFilterDTO {
    if (search.isNullOrEmpty()) return SearchFilterDTO()
    return Gson().fromJson(String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(search)), SearchFilterDTO::class.java)
}
```

And here the SearchFilterDTO and FilterDTO

```
class SearchFilterDTO(
    var currentPage: Int = 1,
    var pageSize: Int = 10,
    var sort: Sort? = null,
    var column: String? = null,
    var filters: List<FilterDTO> = ArrayList<FilterDTO>(),
    var paged: Boolean = true
)

class FilterDTO(
    var field: String,
    var value: Any,
    var comparison: Comparison
)
```